# How to set specific index value of store in extJS comboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a Combo Box.

My requirement is whenever I type any key from the combo the value of that 'key' is get filtered from the store and set as combo value.

Example:  I have these values in drop down.

'ABC',
'ABBR',
'Cricket',
'Footbal'

After clicking on combo if I type `a` the first time 'ABC' value is get set and second type 'ABBR' value will get set.

Here is code of my Combo.

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    editable : true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Now in this case, when I'm typing any key I will get the value filtered from list. But I want not only filtered, I also want the value get set as well.

Here is what I'm trying.

```
listerners:{
    keypress : function(me,e,eopts){
        var store = me.getStore();
        var key = e.event.key;
        var data = store.data.items;
        var results = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].index(key) == 0){
                results.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here all the value starting from that key is stored in result. But I don't know how to set that value from result to combo store.

Any help will be thankfully.

Comment: Do you want to set the value in combobox ??? you are saying that you want to set the value in combo Store

Comment: `listeners` not `listerners`. Also you need to declare `enableKeyEvents: true,` in your combo, if you want `keypress` to work